# "Request is missing required authentication credential" when sending a request to Google Calendar

Tags: reactjs, calendar, google-calendar-api, react-google-login

I'm developing a react calendar app where a user can see their events retrieved from a Google calendar or add their own ones through the app.
I am using `@react-oauth/google` to sign in and get credentials.

Here I can get a `clientId` and `credential`. How can I use them to add/retrieve events to/from a Google Calendar?  Should I add credentials to a request object somehow? (**NOTE**: instead of "" in `CLIENT_ID` and `API_KEY` I inserted some valid values that I got here https://console.cloud.google.com/. Authorized JavaScript origins are http://localhost:3000 and http://localhost)

***error**: {code: 401, data: Array(1), message: 'Request is missing required authentication credent…ogle.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.'}*

```js
import React from "react";
import { GoogleOAuthProvider, GoogleLogin } from "@react-oauth/google";

const GoogleCalendar = () => {
  var gapi = window.gapi;
  var CLIENT_ID =
    "";
  var DISCOVERY_DOCS = [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/calendar/v3/rest",
  ];
  var SCOPES = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events";
  var API_KEY = "";

  const AddEvent = (credentialResponse) => {
    var event = {
      summary: "Google I/O 2015",
      location: "800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103",
      description: "A chance to hear more about Google's developer products.",
      start: {
        dateTime: "2022-05-21T09:00:00-07:00",
        timeZone: "America/Los_Angeles",
      },
      end: {
        dateTime: "2022-05-21T17:00:00-07:00",
        timeZone: "America/Los_Angeles",
      },
      recurrence: ["RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=2"],
      attendees: [
        { email: "lpage@example.com" },
        { email: "sbrin@example.com" },
      ],
      reminders: {
        useDefault: false,
        overrides: [
          { method: "email", minutes: 24 * 60 },
          { method: "popup", minutes: 10 },
        ],
      },
    };

    gapi.client.load("calendar", "v3", () => console.log("bam!"));

    var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.insert({
      calendarId: "primary",
      resource: event,
    });

    request.execute((event) => {
      console.log(event);
      window.open(event.htmlLink);
    });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <GoogleOAuthProvider clientId={CLIENT_ID}>
        <GoogleLogin
          onSuccess={(credentialResponse) => {
            console.log(credentialResponse);
            AddEvent(credentialResponse);
          }}
          onError={() => {
            console.log("Login Failed");
          }}
        />
      </GoogleOAuthProvider>
    </>
  );
};

export default GoogleCalendar;
```

Comment: I don't think you've gone through the authorization process nor provided any credentials when making the API request. Take a look at [this quickstart](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/quickstart/js) to see how to do this client-side.

Answer (score 0):

In order to add the events, the client should be loaded and signed in before calling add events. What you did is correct but you have to wait for the response of client load then you can call add events:

```
gapi.client.setApiKey('YOUR_API_KEY');
gapi.client
  .load('https://content.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/calendar/v3/rest')
  .then((res) => {
    var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.insert({
      calendarId: 'primary',
      resource: event,
    });

    request.execute((event) => {
      console.log(event);
      window.open(event.htmlLink);
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

you need your access_token to authorize to google APIs, you can get it from using Authorization flows from @react-oauth/google by using `useGoogleLogin`